# Is it legal to bring and carry a baton (weapon, bludgeon) into Denmark?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, denmark, cold-weapons

I have a retractable baton which is a self-defense weapon.  (It has no other purpose but as a weapon.)  I am considering bringing it on my trip to Denmark, but of course, only if I can be sure it is allowed.

Are such items legal to bring into Denmark?

Are they legal to carry in Denmark?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the train of thought that made you consider bringing a self-defense weapon to a Western European country? I don't know your current country, but Denmark does not have that much crime. In fact, according to http://www.numbeo.com/crime/rankings_by_country.jsp, it's the 3rd safest place in Europe, and only just misses the top 10 worldwide.

Comment: It's not that I am very worried about the likelihood of being attacked.  Rather it is the particular vulnerability: carrying passport, plane tickets, heavy bags; being in a foreign country where it would not be so easy to deal with the loss of all cash on hand.  The best self-defense strategy would be to rent a car (or travel by taxi), but I am planning to avoid that to save money.

I should add, even if the national crime rates are low, it does not mean there are not high crime rates in certain areas; and foreign travelers are less likely to know which areas to avoid.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Possession of blunt weapons is illegal in Denmark without a specific permit from the police.

Source: [Statutory order concerning weapons and ammunition, etc](https://www.retsinformation.dk/Forms/R0710.aspx?id=158805) (in Danish), §16 part 1 (9).

---

General background (not aimed specifically at the OP who seems already to be willing to follow the rules):

The weapons ban enjoys considerable support among the Danish population* and is vigorously enforced. It is not uncommon for first offenders to receive jail sentences for carrying a knife when going out driking. A baton will probably count as less severe than a knife, but even if you manage to walk free, a 3000-kr ($400) fine can be expected. And averring that the weapon is just for self-defense is unlikely to mollify police or judges.

The foundation of weapons policy debate in Denmark is a near-universal consensus that a nightlife where everybody is armed "for self-defense" is *less safe for everyone* because it increases the risk that trivial drunken altercations will spiral into something tragic, even where everyone thinks they're just defending themselves. Thus, a significant law-enforcement effort goes into keeping such defensive weaponry *out of* potentially unstable situations such as nightlife or football matches -- on the theory that visible and firm enforcement of the weapons ban will help everyone else feel safe enough not to try to arm themselves in respone.

*) At least, as regards items that are clearly and exclusively weapons. In contrast, there is an ongoing debate about whether our regulation of *knives* is overbroad; in some cases it has criminalized knives that were genuinely being used as tools rather than weapons, and a relaxation is presently making its way through parliament.

Comment: How can they possibly enforce that?  I can understand firearm and knife restrictions, and I could see regulating purpose-made retractable batons and the like, but any stick of sufficient length and thickness could be used as an effective blunt weapon.  They can't exactly ban sticks...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I don't know about this specific case but such laws are usually worded like that to (a) not leave unintentional loopholes (b) be enforced only if something else happens to (b1) have something in case they can't be charged with a more serious crime for whatever reason (b2) check boxes in other law (e.g. intent, "using criminal means") (c) control heated situations by starting to enforce it.

Comment: Police and courts do this all the time. Whether something is a weapon or not depends on context. People have been charged with possessing a weapon for carrying a baseball bat, if they have no other baseball equipment and are clearly not going to a baseball game.

Comment: @DJClayworth: IANAL, but my understanding is that the rule applies to items whose only reasonable purpose are to be weapons (like the OP himself describes his baton). In practice it is up to courts to decide whether a particular item is covered. Presumably the reasoning is that if someone considers it worth the trouble to create a thing that's _dedicated to_ being a weapon, the thing must confer enough of a destructive advantage over an improvised club that it's worth the trouble to regulate it, too.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Okay, future reference: If you plan to beat somebody up with a baseball bat, bring a glove as well for appearances.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I've heard actual stories of criminals who'd take a baseball ball as well as a bat in a pocket or boot/trunk of a car when going to rough someone up, in case they were stopped by police on route. Another one I've heard is there was a certain brand of torch/flashlight that was ludicrously large and heavy, which was very popular with taxi and ambulance drivers working at night because they could keep it close by in case they needed to defend themselves against a violent drunk, but could very easily justify it as not being a weapon. These might be urban legends of course.

Comment: @user568458 Such flashlights are hardly urban legend. They are sold under the Maglite brand, usually to law enforcement, though anyone can buy one.

Comment: Do Danes regularly go blunt-weapon hunting or fishing? The first one sounds bad ass the second one sounds incredibly hard.

Comment: First they stun the beast with their intimidating beard.  Then they club the baby seal who didn't see it coming.

Comment: I'm picturing someone standing at the bottom of a waterfall with a baseball bat attempting to knock a fish out of the falls as it comes over. But that sounds kinda silly. Maybe the next question should be "Where can I go blunt-weapon hunting or fishing in Denmark?"

Comment: @Azor-Ahai: You won't find any waterfalls in Denmark anyway. At most a few lazy rapids.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai: Ah, I got it now. The exception is _not_ only for blunt weapons but also covers spears. So spear fishing is allowed.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman They can't ban sticks but they can ban you from carrying a stout stick around the middle of town on a Saturday night without a damned good excuse. Context is everything. If you're walking in the forest, somebody attacks you and you pick up a stick to beat them with, that's self-defence; if you walk into the town centre with a stick just in case somebody attacks you, that's carrying a weapon.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah, right. When I hear things about Scandinavia, I picture the mountains of Iceland and Norway, not the plains of Denmark.

Comment: "Take the ferry to Norway" will add a few hours to the execution time, but is still quite plausible addition to the instructions.